# How to change override function return type in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, inheritance

```
@objc public class A: NSObject
{
    public func getSomething() -> Something
    {
        return Something()
    }
}


@objc public class B: A{
    override public func getSomething() -> SomethingGood
    {
        return SomethingGood()
    }
}


@objc public class C: A{
    ...  
}

@objc public class Something: NSObject{
    var name: String=“”
}

@objc public class SomethingGood: Something{
    var type_id: Int = 0
}
```

Swift compiler shows incompatible types for class B's override function. How do I implement the above? I have tried to use Generics but they are not available for Objective-C developer once the library is built.

I want to be able to use:

A.getSomething() and C.getSomething() to return an object of Something

And B.getSomething() to return an object of SomethingGood.

And I don't want to get two same named function which is func getSomething() for B with two different return types.

Any idea?

The code is used in a static library written in Swift. Once the library is compiled, it should be available to both swift and objective-c.

Answer (score 5):

You can't change the return type, or it wouldn't be an `override`. You can still return `SomethingGood` in this case, just your function declaration can't show the return type as that.

```
@objc public class B: A{
override public func getSomething() -> Something
{
    return SomethingGood()
}

// now whereever you're calling this, if you know it's SomethingGood, you can cast it
if let somethingGood = b.getSomething() as? SomethingGood {
   // do something good
}
```